# How to start a system "beep", from the built-in pc speaker, using a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cygwin

I have written a batch script in an interactive mode, for making some tasks.

Sometimes, These tasks takes a long time to be finished, and then the batch asks if the user wants to go on to the next task, or back to the Batch's Main Menu or... etc

Now, what I want to do, is to add an "Interactive Alarm" command, that sounds a small short beep (Ex: Like the one when we turn on our PCs), to alert the batch user for new questions .

I don't know if this is possible or not, but the most important thing for me, NOT to use a GUI application like WMP or so.. 
I just want to do this from the Background, even If that beep has to be made from the free speaker, or by using a Third-Party CLI Application (Btw, I've Cygwin installed on my Win7-x64) .

Please note that, I will add that alarm command exactly before the interactive questions, waiting for user's answer to get to the next stage, so I can't just finish the batch, by making a real error beep !

So, would somebody please tell me how to do this ?

Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not possible to type the `BEL` directly in (for example) notepad.

To get it, type `echo ^G>>yourbatch.bat` on the command line (don't type `^` `G`, but `<Control>-G`, which will be shown as `^G` on the screen). That puts a strange looking character to the end of your file. That's the `BEL`character 0x007 ("control-G"). Just copy/move it to any `echo` command, you like. Also

```
set /p "input=^Ggive value: "
```

is possible (where the `^G` represents that strange char)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880111/beep-sound-using-batch-file?noredirect=1&lq=1 can you help me out I did not quit understand your answer

Comment: Generating `BEL` is one thing (not `ALT`-`7` but `ALT`-`0`-`0`-`7`, alternatively press `Ctrl+G`), but it doesn't work on its own. You have to `ECHO` it: type `echo ` (including the space), then press **either** `Ctrtl-G` **or**  `ALT` and while you keep it pressed, enter `007`. Then release the `ALT` key. `^G` should appear on your screen. Press ENTER and you should hear the beep (Note: Win10 captures `BEL` and gives you a system sound instead)

Comment: Update (six years later): The command line in current Windows Versions has no direct control over the hardware anymore. The `BEL` is intercepted and replaced with a nice Windows Sound.

Comment: how might you express that in (say) a build file for ant or some such?

Comment: I observed that in standard notepad.exe You can use ascii char call LeftAlt+Numpad7 to create BEL chart. It will pops like full dot on center line • . Then One can copy it i.e. to Nodtapd++. This can be helpful.

Answer (score 76):

**WARNING:** `rundll32.exe Kernel32.dll,Beep 750,300` no longer works well from the command line on modern windows systems as rundll32 no longer accepts integer values (again, through the command line) and ***this will play the beep with the default values which is too long (and frequency is irritating)***:

```
REM Again, with warnings about running this from the command line...
rundll32.exe Kernel32.dll,Beep 750,300
```

or

```
rundll32.exe cmdext.dll,MessageBeepStub
```

or

```
rundll32 user32.dll,MessageBeep
```

With rundll functions you won't need special symbols like `^G`. With the first method you can also set the [frequency and the time you want](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) to beep, though see the warning that those parameters no longer work on modern systems from the command line and will instead play the annoying defaults.

---

**UPDATE**

Other options are calling [`Console.Beep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep#system-console-beep(system-int32-system-int32)) from .NET using PowerShell:

```
powershell "[console]::beep(500,300)"
```

or using [systemSounds.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/systemSounds.bat)

```
call systemsounds.bat beep
```

The capability of beeping depends on the mainboard and if the mainboard has a system speaker - which has increasingly become a rarity as systems tend to depend solely on "normal" speakers instead. An alternative is to play sound through those speakers. Here are some options:

Using the speaking capabilities of the [`SAPI.SpVoice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723602(v=vs.85)):

```
mshta "javascript:code(close((V=(v=new ActiveXObject('SAPI.SpVoice')).GetVoices()).count&&v.Speak('beep')))"
```

Here [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/say.bat) is wrapped in a batch file and the words can be passed as an argument.

`SAPI.SpVoice` can be used for playing WAV files and you have some packaged with the default Windows installation. You can use this [script](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/spplayer.bat):

```
spplayer.bat  "C:\Windows\Media\Windows Navigation Start.wav"
```

Another option: [Using the windows media player active-x objects](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/mediarunner.bat) to play a sound. On Windows XP it was not installed by default, but I think for the newer Windows versions it is. It also can play MP3 files:

```
call mediarunner.bat "C:\Windows\Media\Ring03.wav"
```

And one that is a little bit obscure - using the `<bgsound>` tag from internet explorer (which also can play mp3 files). Here's the [script](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/soundPlayer.bat):

```
call soundplayer.bat "C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav"
```

And here's a way to use the [**BEL** character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character) to produce sound with easy to copy-paste code (I've called it a `beeper.bat`):

```
@echo off
setlocal
::Define a Linefeed variable
(set LF=^
%=-=%
)
  
for /f eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in (
   'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x07"'
) do echo(%%A
```

Comment: Hey! This works fine under win10. Does it under win7 as well? Cannot test.

Comment: @Jewenile - yes it will.

Comment: Thx. Btw is there any other sound to pick from than just this MessageBeep? I was unsuccessful in my search.

Comment: @Jewenile  - check the last link in the answer - there you can choose bettwen few system sounds. You can also play all media files that comes packed with the windows  (from `C:\Windows\Media`) - check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37788853/388389

Comment: This has the major advantage of working from the Atom command-process extension.

Comment: Everytime I run it I get a continuous beep that won't stop, but each time with a different frequency, which can be very high. How do I turn it off without reboot?

Comment: @MartinJ.H. - you can execute `taskkill /im rundll32.exe /f` . For newer windows versions you cant anymore pass more arguments to the rundll functions. I'll try to update my script with better usage of `Kernel32` function , but the second line should work without worries.

Comment: @npocmaka - thanks for the summary. May I suggest to add this warning / caveat of neverending beep and how to stop it to your answer, please? (TBH, that was one annoying sound that would not stop! :-)

Comment: Echoing the other comments here. The first command beeped incessantly. Thankfully I knew it was coming and thanks to your input I could just copy-paste the kill command. But the other suggestions don't actually appear to work on W10.

Comment: Headphone users take caution!! This almost made my ears bleed

Comment: "_this does not work well on modern windows systems as rundll32 no longer accepts integer values through command line and this will play the beep with the default values which is too long_" Good heavens please put this first. Actually, if you don't mind, I'm going to edit the answer to include this warning.

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing something but Windows 10 just generates an artificial beep from the sound card for these methods, such as `[console]::beep(500,300)`.  Is there a way to get it to *actually* beep from the PC speaker itself?

Comment: @ruffin sir you probably saved a lot people's headaches. I can vouch for one; though curiosity got the better of me and I tested it, followed by disabling of sound driver shortly after

Answer (score 15):

The following can be used to issue a beep

- without pausing the script
- without creating a new line.
- without requiring the use of a non-printable character

```bat
 Echo/| CHOICE /N 2> nul & rem BEL
```

It is a deliberate misuse of the choice command, that Echo's nothing via a pipe to Choice, causing a non-breaking error. STDERR is redirected to nul, and the default choice prompt is suppressed via the `/N` switch, meaning no new line is output.

If for some reason you wanted to reuse this annoying tone throughout a script, you could define it as a macro

```
Set "BEL=Echo/| CHOICE /N 2> nul"
%BEL%
```

Comment: This works but issues two beeps somehow. I was trying to use CHOICE command as well because I was using CHOICE for another task in my script and heard that beep when I pressed a key that wasn't allowed. I figured there must be a way. But not sure why it's two beeps with this code.

Comment: @HTWingNut: The cure is simple: `set /P "=X" < nul | CHOICE /N 2> nul`

Comment: This is how to batch file not wait till beep is played, but continue immediatelly `start "" /B cmd /C"set /P "=X" < nul | CHOICE /N 2> nul"`

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
echo BEEP.BAT by CSS---
echo PRESS ANY KEY TO HEAR A BEEP...
PAUSE>NUL
ECHO 
echo I BEEPED
PAUSE
```

there is an ASCII control code ^G after the echo. Just copy this code, and save it as ASCII/ANSI using a text editor.

Comment: (!) to make this work, don't copy the code from this post (as displayed) directly but click "edit" first and copy the listing from the markdown.

Answer (score 3):

Call [Console.Beep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep#system-console-beep(system-int32-system-int32)) from .NET using PowerShell:

```
powershell.exe [console]::beep(500,600)
```

So programmatically in Node.js it would look like this (Python or C would be similar):

```js
require("child_process").exec("powershell.exe [console]::beep(500,600)");
```

Answer (score 1):

use ECHO command to echo a CTRL G

Answer (score 1):

I think the better solution is echoing a `^G` to a file from the cmd prompt and then type that file from within the script, that way you don't need to include control characteres in the batch file itself:

```
C:\> echo ^G>beep.snd
```

Now there's an ASCII 007 char in the "beep.snd" file, then from your .bat file all you have to do is type it or copy to the screen:

```
type beep.snd
```

or

```
copy beep.snd con > nul
```

Comment: Since the beep requires a bit of time to run through (about 2 seconds to play the full sound on win 10 default), a slight timeout might be necessary to hear the beep. EG
`ECHO 

timeout 2`
(the beep control character is right after ECHO in the example)

Comment: or just create a batch file `beep.bat` which just contains `ECHO ^G`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this line somewhere in your batch file,
whenever you want to make a beep sound:

```
RunDLL32 User32.dll,MessageBeep
```

It plays built-in beep sound effect in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I find this variation on @npocmaka version works for me with Windows 10:

```
REM This captures the Bell as a variable.
for /f %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%forfiles.exe /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo 0x07"') do set "bel=%%g"
REM This produces the Bell sound.
set /P "=%bel%"<NUL
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me..

[image]

there was a special character in line 4 which stackoverflow was omitting,
code's pasted here:
[hashb.in/long](https://hashb.in/#AIUQwgEg8gBFBi8BQAXAligNgUxgIW2wAdsAnJALhQHsikBwAPgDsBXTJU7AWxiIENWAZ2yo03bNVYoYAZhgB6ZtQBGXfgGskAc2o0YNIkA=)

and line 5 and 6 can be used interchangeably of course.