# Is there a Soundplayer difference in Powershell v .bat Call?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, audio

As part of a practical joke I made a powershell script that raises the volume to the maximum level and plays 1 of 10 fart noises. It is called by a .bat.

When I run it in the Powershell ISE program, it works perfectly but when I called the PS1 from the .bat file, the sound did not issue (but other aspects of the script worked). As I was debugging, I added the "strange part" (see below) and the .bat file began to work and played a random noise each time (not just sound 0)

What is the reason for this?

```
$a=0
while ($a -lt 100){
$obj = new-object -com wscript.shell
$obj.SendKeys([char]175)
$a=$a+1
}

$x= random(10)
$sound = new-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer
$file="S:\Test\farts\$x.wav"
$sound.SoundLocation=$file
$sound.Play()
write-host $x
```

## The Strange part V

```
& soundplayer.play("S:\Test\farts\0.wav");
```

(called by @powershell.exe -executionpolicy Bypass -file S:\POWERSHELL_SCRIPTS\fart.ps1)

Comment: could you paste the whole script....im really not sure where the soundplayer is called?

Comment: "& soundplayer.play("S:\Test\farts\0.wav");" why are you even calling that? if yoou are alreadying playing it from the PS1 script??

Comment: Parts of your question do not make sense. You've shown the following, `& soundplayer.play("S:\Test\farts\0.wav");` is that part of the powershell script file or it's output? if not how is it relevant? You also show a command line to invoke the powershell script, `@powershell.exe -executionpolicy Bypass -file S:\POWERSHELL_SCRIPTS\fart.ps1`; Is that part of the `.bat` file or all of it?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37788853/388389

Comment: Both grey areas comprise my ps1 script. It is called by a .bat. The upper part works as a .ps1 but when the .bat file calls the .ps1, no sound comes out.


That extra line shouldn't make sense, but the .bat works properly with it (calling a random sound, not just #0 each time). My question is why the upper part of the script worked in the PS1 but not from the .bat and why that extra line caused the .bat to work?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to play with your script for a while and was surprised that you are in did correct, the sound doesn't play when not running the script within an interactive powershell.

After some digging found this thread on MSDN which explains why:

> The Media Player requires an interactive UI for security purposes.

https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2af7ca7a-52aa-4d0a-9eb7-38b863e66d45/powershell-alarm-sound-in-task-scheduler-with-option-quotrun-whether-user-is-logged-on-or?forum=Offtopic

If you just wanted to play some sound (and not farts..) I would use:

```bsh
[system.Console]::beep(<Frequency>,<Time in ms>)
```

I use it for many scripts alerting me about stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
powershell -Command "& {$player = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer Desktop/Alarm08.wav; $player.Play()}"
```

has the same issues as your script.

Kaki gadol's answer guided me to the following command:

```
powershell -NoExit -Command "& {$player = New-Object System.Media.SoundPlayer Desktop/Alarm08.wav; $player.Play(); sleep 3; exit}"
```

The "NoExit" command line parameter keeps the powershell session interactive enough for the media player to make sound. The "sleep 3; exit" part then exits the session, so you do not need to exit manually. The only issue is that the sound stops after 3 seconds. To solve that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Based on this, adding sufficient sleep and exit to your script may work. Maybe you need to guide the victim^H^H^H^H^H^H user of your script into invoking it using the "-noExit" command line option.