# How to set a specific resolution for batch file window?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ascii

I want to set a specific resolution for this batch file window. how to set it.? And can I embed an mp3 audio file to it? I want it to play during startup while it shows the welcome in batch file window. See the code you will get a clear idea, what I want to do.
-Thank You

```
@echo off
color 0a
title welcome 
echo welcome batch


echo #     # ####### #        #####  ####### #     # #######     
echo #  #  # #       #       #     # #     # ##   ## #          
echo #  #  # #       #       #       #     # # # # # #            
echo #  #  # #####   #       #       #     # #  #  # #####       
echo #  #  # #       #       #       #     # #     # #           
echo #  #  # #       #       #     # #     # #     # #           
echo  ## ##  ####### #######  #####  ####### #     # #######       
>NUL TIMEOUT /T 10 /NOBREAK
```

Comment: And no, you can't embed audio.

Comment: for playing sound through bat file check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37788853/388389