# nircmd mediaplay: access is denied

Tags: batch-file, nircmd

I'm trying to make a bat file that when launched will open a mediafile and close after x-number milliseconds.

> mediaplay [play time] [audio file]

I'm trying to use nircmd's media play command, but it dosen't recognize it. I've tried the following codes in cmd.

```
C:\Users\Lind>mediaplay 10000 "C:\Users\Lind\Music\1.mp3"
'mediaplay' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

I've also tried this but nothing happend

```
C:\Users\Lind>nircmd.exe mediaplay 10000 "C:\Users\Lind>Music>1.mp3"
```

**************************************Update************************************

I found out that I've made a mistake in the mp3 file directory name, now it just says

```
C:\Users\Lind>nircmd.exe mediaplay 10000 "C:\Users\Lind>Music\1.mp3"

Access is denied.
```

I've tried using cmd as an adminstrator, but then nothing happens.

Comment: Your second attempt would have worked if you had used `C:\Users\Lind\Music\1.mp3` as the path instead.

Comment: Your path is still wrong. Change the `>` after Lind to a `\`.

Comment: to avoid usage of external tools to play audio files , you might want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37788853/388389

Answer (score 1):

If you do not provide the location of `nircmd.exe` you will need to make sure that `nircmd.exe` resides within the current directory or a location defined under `%PATH%`:

Here's an example for you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem MediaPlay command
Set "mp="C:\Users\Lind\Utilities\NirSoft\nircmd.exe" MediaPlay"

Rem MusicFile location
Set "mf=C:\Users\Lind\Music\1.mp3"

Rem MilliSeconds
Set "ms=10000"

Rem Start it
Start "" %mp% %ms% "%mf%"
```

Just change the values after the **`=`** for the three `Set` statements as required, *(but do not remove or change any of the **`"`**'s)*.

**Note:** `nircmd.exe` and `nircmdc.exe` are both flagged as potential security threats by most antivirus/antimalware programs. If you have one of those then, you'd have to see if you can make an exception for it to run from within your security software.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute any external command (ie. any command that is not internal to `cmd.exe` itself), then you need to do one of the following:

1. Specify the precise location of the executable (eg use `"c:\wherever\your\mediaplay\is located\mediaplay"` in place of `mediaplay` (quotes required if the path or executable name contains separators like spaces))
2. Include the directoryname for `mediaplay` into the `path` variable. This can be done on a permanent basis by using `Control Panel>System>Advanced System Settings>Advanced>Environment Variables` or preferably by using a dedicated editor like `Path Editor` or on a temporary basis by prefixing `that path;` to the `path` variable within a batch or manually from the prompt.
3. Navigate to the `mediaplayer` directory using the three lines "pushd *mediaplayerdirectoryname*", "mediaplayer...", "popd" (all without the quotes)

The last method is a special case of the second which uses the windows' executable-search strategy to look for an executable first in the current directory, and then in each directory specified in the `path` variable in turn until the executable is found.

Comment: But i think it's not internal to cmd.exe itself, mediaplay is a command from nircmd. Although really appreciate all the help.

Comment: But i found out but i've made a mistake in the mp3 file directory name, now it just says `C:\Users\Lind>nircmd.exe mediaplay 10000 "C:\Users\Lind>Music\1.mp3"
Access is denied.`

Comment: no, windows makes a pop-up that says "This app can't run on your pc"

Comment: i've triad using cmd as an adminstrator, but then nothing happens

Comment: It's certainly not an internal command to `cmd`, therefore one of the three techniques I mentioned should work. `C:\Users\Lind>Music\1.mp3` is incorrect. A directory-delimiter is `\`. `>` is a redirector. The pop-up is from the operating system itself indicating that it's found the executable, but can't run it. Possibly it's too old a version and you need a new version of `nircmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you didn't turn the nircmd.exe file into a empty file using that command you just did. It should not be a 0kb file. I made the same mistake and turned my exe into a empty file.

Reinstall Nircmd and you should be good with the new command.