# Batch file to pings an IP continuously and play alert beep on 2 or more ping losses

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing, ping

I am trying to create a Batch file/ cmd file to ping a given IP continuously (ping 8.8.8.8 -t) along with functions

1.if ping fails for more than "X" times - start a continuous beep alert

2.if ping kicks back to success - stop the beep alert

I have seen some batch files that change color of screen according to the ping success/failure, is it possible to call an audio alert on fail and stop it on success.

Comment: Sounds good sauce boss. Now do it yourself. Stack Overflow is a place where people meet into problems with their code and search help.

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079534/how-to-start-a-system-beep-from-the-built-in-pc-speaker-using-a-batch-file/27080437?r=SearchResults&s=1|30.2466#27080437)

Answer (score 0):

Power Shell is a good place to start with that sort of thing.  One or more loops and [Test-Connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection) and [Test-NetConnection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/nettcpip/test-netconnection) will get you started.