# cmd batch - command or alias for "localized yes message or letter" for scripts

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a script of cmd batch to `takeown` of all files in a folder. Now I am facing a problem. `takeown` is localised into Spanish in my OS and it requires `s` instead of `y` for confirming after `/d` switch:

```
:: for English it's Y, but for Spanish it is S
takeown /f "c:\cygwin" /r /d Y
```

I want to be generic to use it in different locale. Like, with a script, it works simutaneously in English, Spanish, German, French...

For that purpose, I want to know if there is a global alias for `YES` and `NO` letter in cmd. Or, the result of some command which gives us the two letters, and work also for `takeown`.

PS: a bold "No, it is impossible" is also a valid answer, if with proper reasoning.

BTW, the Spanish version of `takeown /d` is:

```
/D      pregunta             Respuesta predeterminada usada cuando el
                             usuario actual no tiene el permiso "listar
                             carpeta" en un directorio. Esto ocurre al
                             trabajar de manera recursiva (/R) con
                             subdirectorios. Son valores válidos "S" para
                             tomar posesión y "N" para omitir.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben Personick's answer doesn't work for me (German Windows), so I expanded it a bit (the trick to "ask" `takeown` itself which answers are valid is great):

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /F delims^=^"^ Tokens^=2^,4 %%A IN ('takeown /? ^| findstr /R " \"[A-Z]\" "') DO ( 
    ECHO Debug: Take: "%%A" Skip: "%%B"
    if not defined take (
      set "take=%%~A"
      if not "%%~B" == "" set "skip=%%~B" 
    ) else set "skip=%%~A" 
)
set take
set skip
```

Output:

```
Debug: Take: "J" Skip: ""
Debug: Take: "N" Skip: ""
take=J
skip=N
```

for reference the relevant part of `takeown /?`:

```
/D        Aufforderung       Standardantwort, die verwendet wird, wenn der
                             aktuelle Benutzer nicht die Berechtigung
                             "Ordner auflisten" für ein Verzeichnis hat.
                             Tritt bei der rekursiven Bearbeitung (/R)
                             von Unterverzeichnissen auf. Gültige Werte
                             sind "J" zum Übernehmen der Besitzrechte
                             oder "N" zum Auslassen dieses Schrittes.
```

I guess in some languages the "YES" and "NO" options are in the same line and in other languages they are in two separate lines.

**EDIT**  comments show that although the choices (`Y` or `N`) are localized, the help text doesn't necessarily reflect that. `choice` is one of the few commands that show you the possible inputs:

```
C:\>choice
[J,N]?
```

and it can be talked into not actually waiting for input by redirecting `NUL` to STDIN. `2>nul` suppresses the error message:

```
C:\>choice <nul 2>nul
[J,N]?
C:\>
```

So with a `for /f` around, we can catch the letters:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[,]" %%a in ('"choice <nul 2>nul"') do set "yes=%%a" & set "no=%%b"
echo Press %yes% for yes and %no% for no
```

Comment: It is not universal because it does not work for Spanish... I am aware of this solution but we cannot anticipate what `takeown /?` gives us in each locale. See my edit to the question.

Comment: @WesternGun Could you please provide the `/D` part of the Spanish version of `takeown /?` (edit it into your question or my answer for proper formatting)

Comment: Edited, see the question.

Comment: works for me. Output: `Debug: Take: "S" Skip: ""`, `Debug: Take: "N" Skip: ""`, `take=S`, `skip=N`

Comment: Do you have localized `takeown` in your os? I mean, with the paragraph it may work, but here running the script gets me `ERROR: sintaxis no válida.`.

Comment: I put the text in a .bat` file, added `@more +1 2%~f02 & goto :eof` as the first line and used that instead of `takeown /?`   The syntax error is because of a missing `/?` (see corrected code)

Comment: Now it works. Yes.... So I can mark it as answer. So, it is searching the second and the third `" "` in the `takeown /?` `/d` line, right? What if in the output of `takeown` help text in some language, the sequence of words is reordered, and that the second and the third double quoted string is not what we look for?

Comment: Now **that** is a perfect answer... I really appreciate that. I was playing with pipe and redirect to `nul` but didn't know how. It deserves double upvote.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do this to catch the Responses** as they are always a single character surrounded by double quotes, **then you can use them as needed**

```
for /F  delims^=^"^ Tokens^=2^,4 %A IN ('takeown /? ^| FIndStr /R /C:" """[A-Z]""" "') DO @( ECHO.Take: "%~A" Skip: "%~B" )
```

## For your Needs you can simply use:

```
for /F  delims^=^"^ Tokens^=2 %%A IN ('TakeOwn /?') DO @( TakeOwn /f "c:\cygwin" /r /d %%A  )
```

## For a more detailed breakdown:

```
for /F  delims^=^"^ Tokens^=2^,4 %%A IN (
'takeown /?
^|
 FIndStr /R /C:" """[A-Z]""" "
') DO (
    SET "_TakeOwn_YES=%%~A"
    SET "_TakeOwn_NO=%%~B"
)

takeown /d %_TakeOwn_YES%
```

I noticed some feedback about the Takeown not being localized, so that is unfortunate, but the Author of this post also suggested `CHOICE` would always be localized in a post a little earlier, so we can just use that.

I played around with `Choice` using the methods one often does with `DATE` and `SET /P` and found it was an easy of defining the Affirmative and Negative Choices for use with TakeOwn or any other choice that is localized.

**Below pulls both Answers and shows them**

```
FOR /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=[,]" %A IN ('
  echo.^|choice 2^>NUL
') DO @(
  ECHO.Affirmative: "%~A" Negative:  "%~B"
)
```

## For your Needs you can simply use:

```
FOR /F "Tokens=1 Delims=[," %%A IN ('echo.^|choice 2^>NUL') DO @( TakeOwn /f "c:\cygwin" /r /d %%A  )
```

Hope that is helpful :)

Looks like Stephan responded with a similar method to that based off the OP's suggestion of Choice while I was writing this and reposting something I noticed I had open in another window,  Nicely Done @Stephan :)

Comment: Good work! Thanks! I must say I have a lot to learn.. because you both easily came out with a script when you know `choice` is the right path to go, while I cannot.

Comment: Thanks @WeaterGun!  I made a push to write CMD scripts wherever possible to avoid incompatability between windows versions and other langs orrelying on 3rd party utilities, wherever possible, so I have a lot of experiance solving "gotchas"!  To be sure, I write a lot more PS scripts today, but CMD is often more fun, and for some things you need both!  :)

Comment: `CMD is ofter more fun`. hm.. it is difficult to write them... Oh one thing: `choice` is not present in versions previous to Vista, right?

Comment: @WesternGun It is difficult because the syntax and caveats are not well understood by most, and often a little esoteric to explain.  `Choice` is Available in Windows 2003 and onward (so Win 2k3, 2k3R2, Vista, 7, 2k8,2k8R2, 8, 8.1, 2012,2012R2, 10, 2016, 2019)  IN Windows XP is it availbale only if the Windows XP Resource Kit is installed.

Answer (score 1):

This command will use /d S if the system locale is 0C0A (Spanish), else /d Y

```
for /f "skip=2" %%a in ('"wmic os get locale | sort /r"') do if /i %%a EQU 0C0A ( takeown /f "c:\cygwin" /r /d S ) else ( takeown /f "c:\cygwin" /r /d Y )
```

Comment: Yes thats right, but I want it to be generic(i.e., a global solution which works in every language, like in German it should be `J` or something else), so I want to know if there is some command getting this "default letter for Yes" considering locale. PS: a bold NO is also a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to determine Yes, No, and All responses (complete words), as well as the initial letters. I originally developed this at [Determine Yes/No/All string for current locale](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5391) over at the DosTips.com forum.

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :getYesNoAll

:: Show Results
set Response

exit /b


:getYesNoAll
pushd "%temp%"
copy nul getYesNoAll.tmp >nul
set "ResponseYes="
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=(/)" %%A in (
  '"<nul copy /-y nul getYesNoAll.tmp"'
) do if not defined ResponseYes (
  set "ResponseYes=%%A"
  set "ResponseNo=%%B"
  set "ResponseAll=%%C"
)
set "ResponseY=%ResponseYes:~0,1%"
set "ResponseN=%ResponseNo:~0,1%"
set "ResponseA=%ResponseAll:~0,1%"
del "getYesNoAll.tmp"
popd
exit /b
```

-- Output on my English machine --

```
ResponseA=A
ResponseAll=All
ResponseN=N
ResponseNo=No
ResponseY=Y
ResponseYes=Yes
```

Some design points that might not be obvious:

- I create a temp file with known name to guarantee file name does not contain delimiter character `(` or `)`. Note that `/` can't appear in name or path anyway.
- I create the file in `%temp%` to "guarantee" user has write access.
- I `PUSHD` to the `%temp%` directory to guarantee path is not included in `COPY` output. Unlikely, but a non-standard `%temp%` value could include `(` or `)`.
- I am assuming that `COPY` and `TAKEOWN` use the same responses for Yes and No. I use `COPY` because it is easier and more reliable to parse the output.
- As Stephan points out in his comment, I also assume the first letter of each response is unique.

Comment: another assumption you implicitly take:: "the one-letter options are always the first letter of the complete-word options". I wouldn't take that as a fact until verified in all possible languages. There might be languages where `all` starts with the same letter as `yes` or `no` - or even `yes` and `no` might start with the same letter, forcing the one-letter option NOT to be the first letter on (at least) one option.

Comment: @Stephan - Yes. I'm not aware of a situation where the response must be a single letter - as far as I know, the complete response can be used, and the single letter responses can be ignored. I'm tempted to remove the single letter responses from my answer.

Comment: `takeown /f "c:\nonexistent.file" /r /d Yes` gives `ERROR: Invalid syntax. 'Yes' value is not allowed for '/d' option`, while `takeown /f "c:\nonexistent.file" /r /d Y` gives (expected): `ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified`. So at least `takeown` *needs*  the one-letter option.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a command which may work: `choice`. It is also localised. I may elaborate tomorrow.

Comment: but with `choice` you can define your choices with the `/c` switch

Comment: Yes, but I want to get the default letters. Like, if I `choice`, the result would be `[S,N]` for Spanish. Now I know the two letters are `S` and `N`. That is what I want to know.

Comment: @Stephan sorry but I rolled back your edit, because you search in help text of `choice` in your edit, but in Spanish OS, if you `choice`, you will get `[S,N]` as default letters, and in the help text of `choice /?`, you will see `Y` and `N`, which is the default case *only for English*. That is why I want to stress that **don't trust help text, because i18n translation may not cover them**.

Comment: No problem (the German translation is correct). But I have another one (get the Control-C similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079534/how-to-start-a-system-beep-from-the-built-in-pc-speaker-using-a-batch-file/27080437?r=SearchResults&s=1|29.7173#27080437)): `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[,]" %%a in ('echo/X^|choice') do set "yes=%%a" & set "no=%%b"`, where the `X` is the Control-C (`ASC(003)`) (but produces some sound - if you can live with that)

Comment: I believe the following should normally work: `for /f "delims=[,] tokens=1,2" %%A in ('"choice <nul 2>nul"') do set ResultY=%%A&set ResultN=%%B`. But there may problems - Some older versions of Windows (XP) have different versions of CHOICE, and or CHOICE may be missing entirely. I'm not sure if the older version gives the same result, and obviously missing CHOICE is a non-starter.